# SwiftUI splitting words in Text View mid-word

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI text view that is being fed a string. In both my watchOS app and iOS app, when I input a long word (like "friendship"), it cuts the words off mid-word.  If I put in more words, it fixes it (sometimes), but for a single word that is more than 6 or 7 characters, it splits the word in the middle:

(K.screenSize values are just references to UIScreen.main.bounds.width or UIScreen.main.bounds.height, and textColor is just reference to calculated value of color)

iOS text view:

```
 Text("Friendship")
           .foregroundColor(textColor)
           .font(.system(size: K.ScreenSize.screenHeight / 10))
           .lineLimit(nil)
           .minimumScaleFactor(0.05)
           .padding(.horizontal, K.ScreenSize.screenWidth / 10)
           .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

watchOS text view:

```
Text("Friendship")
          .foregroundColor(.green)
          .font(.system(size: K.ScreenSize.screenHeight / 2))
          .lineLimit(nil)
          .minimumScaleFactor(0.05)
```

here's some screenshots (ios and watchos):

[image: ios screenshot]

[image: watchos screenshot]

Comment: I don't see a question mark in this entire question. What's the desired outcome here, Ben? Shrink the font to fit or?

Comment: Sorry, I basically want the type to be as large as possible in my view, and the text should not mi-word when it goes down to the next line. So, this word should just be shown smaller in the view, but if more words are added it would add them in…it seems like Swift ui isn’t aware of individual words and is just splitting words to fit all the characters on screen.